# Prolog - How can I modify this clause to be able to print it in-depth first search DFS?

Tags: prolog

I was wondering how to modify the clause `recorrido/2` to print it in depth first search, I have this so far:

input

```
arc(1,2).
arc(1,3).
arc(2,4).
arc(2,5).
arc(3,6).
arc(3,7).
arc(4,8).
arc(4,9).
arc(5,10).
arc(5,11).
arc(6,12).
arc(6,13).
arc(7,14).
arc(7,15).
```

```
imprime([]).
imprime([A|B]):-
 write(A),nl,
 imprime(B).

bimprime([]).
bimprime([A|B]):-
 bimprime(B),
 write(A),nl.
```

Comment: Please add an example with expected input and output

Comment: It would be helpful if you translate predicate names to english.

Comment: I guess it's a unidirectional graph, right? "imprime"/"biprime" is less clear than something like "traverse" which is what you possibly want. Do you care about cycles? Still an example output would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would pass a `level` argument to the recursive function, to be incremented just before the recursive call.

```erlang
recorrido(X,Z):- recorrido(X,Z,0).
recorrido(X,Z,L):- arco(X,Z),indent(L,Z).
recorrido(X,Z,L):- arco(X,Y),indent(L,Y),N is L+1,recorrido(Y,Z,N).
```

indent/2 would place some space, proportional to the current level, before the value. For instance

```erlang
indent(L,V) :- forall(between(0,L,_),write('  ')),writeln(V).
```

Since this a bit too much verbose for my taste, I usually use a list instead of an integer to mark the level:

```erlang
recorrido(X,Z):- recorrido(X,Z,[]).
recorrido(X,Z,L):- arco(X,Z),indent(L,Z).
recorrido(X,Z,L):- arco(X,Y),indent(L,Y),recorrido(Y,Z,[-|L]).

indent(L,V) :- forall(member(_,L),write('  ')),writeln(V).
```